# i am getting this error : " UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Requesting_books' referenced before assignment "

Tags: python, flask

i want to use the variable " Requesting_books ", but everytime i am getting this error : "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Requesting_books' referenced before assignment". Actually i want to use this variable in my jinja template so that i can show search results. Please Help me !

```
@app.route('/request books', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/get books', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def requesting_for_books():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        requesting = mongo.db.mylogin
        Requesting_books = requesting.find_one({'name' : request.form['bookname']})
    return render_template('get_books.html', title="Get Books", my_book=Requesting_books['name'])
```

Comment: You assign something to `Requesting_books` only if `request.method == 'POST'`. In other cases, it is undefined (i.e. *Unbound*), as the error says. You have to do something in `else`.

Comment: What `if request.method != 'POST'`…?!

Comment: Thank you verry much, you guys really saved me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an `else` block because if `request.method` is not `'POST'` no variable will be assigned .

```
@app.route('/request books', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/get books', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def requesting_for_books():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        requesting = mongo.db.mylogin
        Requesting_books = requesting.find_one({'name' : request.form['bookname']})
        return render_template('get_books.html', title="Get Books", my_book=Requesting_books['name']) #<--- Move return into the if block
    else:
        #Do something if request.method is not "POST"
```